# My app works fine on Android 9 but Keeps Crashing on Android 10

Tags: android, crash, android-10.0

Here is the Manifest file, the app works fine on all versions below android 9 but keeps stopping on android 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.MyApplication"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.WelcomeScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!--<activity-->
        <!--android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"-->
        <!--android:launchMode="singleTask">-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />-->

            <!--<data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />-->

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    <!--</activity>-->
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/p_apikey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.razorpay.ApiKey"
        android:value="rzp_live_uwWRXIWmWvbvej"
        />
    <!-- <service -->
    <!-- android:name=".service.OrderStatusService" -->
    <!-- android:exported="false" /> -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.AddCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.OtpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.MobileNumberActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/forgot_password"
        android:parentActivityName="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.HotelViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:label="Change Password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.FavouritesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.RecommendedListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.EditAccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.SetDeliveryLocationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.SaveDeliveryLocationActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ManageAddressActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.AccountPaymentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.OrdersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.FilterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ViewCartActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.PastOrderDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.OtherHelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.NotificationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.PromotionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.CurrentOrderDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.AddMoneyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.WalletActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="3aef7a5b05836cf8166f23c95e43c52517bee917" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ResetPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.PaymentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.SecretKeyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <!--<provider-->
        <!--android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"-->
        <!--android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"-->
        <!--android:exported="false"-->
        <!--android:grantUriPermissions="true">-->
        <!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"-->
            <!--android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />-->
    <!--</provider>-->

    <activity
        android:name="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.ProductDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:parentActivityName="com.shops.nicofoods.activities.HotelViewActivity"
    />
</application>
```

ERROR-LOGCAT

2020-01-28 17:59:44.502 1684-1684/? E/shops.nicofood: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-01-28 17:59:45.028 1684-1684/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.shops.nicofoods cmp=com.shops.nicofoods/.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6d8a895 u0a134 SVC  idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

VERBOSE-LOGCAT

2020-01-28 17:59:44.484 1684-1684/? I/shops.nicofood: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-01-28 17:59:44.502 1684-1684/? E/shops.nicofood: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-01-28 17:59:44.503 1684-1684/? W/shops.nicofood: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-01-28 17:59:44.579 1684-1684/? I/shops.nicofood: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-01-28 17:59:44.969 1684-1684/? I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2020-01-28 17:59:44.969 1684-1684/? I/MultiDex: Installing application
2020-01-28 17:59:44.969 1684-1684/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2020-01-28 17:59:44.996 1684-1684/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2020-01-28 17:59:45.028 1684-1684/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.shops.nicofoods cmp=com.shops.nicofoods/.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6d8a895 u0a134 SVC  idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
2020-01-28 17:59:45.029 1684-1684/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2020-01-28 17:59:45.068 1684-1684/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11400
2020-01-28 17:59:45.068 1684-1684/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-01-28 17:59:45.109 1684-1684/? V/FA: Collection enabled
2020-01-28 17:59:45.109 1684-1684/? V/FA: App package, google app id: com.shops.nicofoods, 1:72318950278:android:b6b96c0c7eee2376792a07
2020-01-28 17:59:45.111 1684-1684/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.shops.nicofoods
2020-01-28 17:59:45.111 1684-1684/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-01-28 17:59:45.168 1684-1684/? V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -1646145356
2020-01-28 17:59:45.185 1684-1684/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2020-01-28 17:59:45.189 1684-1684/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-01-28 17:59:45.258 1684-1724/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2020-01-28 17:59:45.278 1684-1724/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-01-28 17:59:45.341 1684-1724/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2020-01-28 17:59:45.341 1684-1724/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-01-28 17:59:45.431 1684-1727/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-01-28 17:59:45.586 1684-1684/com.shops.nicofoods I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.17.dev
2020-01-28 17:59:45.794 1684-1684/com.shops.nicofoods I/ActivityThread: handleStopService: token=android.os.BinderProxy@51eed9c not found.
2020-01-28 17:59:45.925 1684-1724/com.shops.nicofoods D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-01-28 17:59:45.926 1684-1724/com.shops.nicofoods V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2020-01-28 17:59:45.937 1684-1759/com.shops.nicofoods W/shops.nicofood: Verification of void com.crashlytics.android.answers.EnabledSessionAnalyticsManagerStrategy.setAnalyticsSettingsData(io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AnalyticsSettingsData, java.lang.String) took 109.554ms
2020-01-28 17:59:51.057 1684-1724/com.shops.nicofoods V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-01-28 18:00:26.136 1684-1737/com.shops.nicofoods E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
2020-01-28 18:00:26.141 1684-1735/com.shops.nicofoods E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
2020-01-28 18:00:26.143 1684-1740/com.shops.nicofoods W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!

Comment: Please post your crash log and why did you repeat same text again and again?

Comment: Please add the errorlog. There are a lot of double declarations in your files

Comment: Error Log has been Updated in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

```
2020-01-28 17:59:45.028 1684-1684/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
```

Not sure but, Looks like you might have older play service libraries from which services are not able to start in the background due to new restrictions in android 10.

So try to update FCM/play services library which might have updates services.

Also, make sure emulator having latest gapps